# If I want to use hibernate with Annotation, do I have to use javax.persistence.*?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations

I know hibernate is an implementation of JPA, and also has its own features. I'm trying to use hibernate with annotations, but I found I have to use some annotations under package "javax.persistence.*", such as: Column, OneToMany, ManyToOne, and so on.

I don't want to use JPA, but I can't found same annotations like OneToMany under package "org.hibernate.annotations". So, are the jpa annatations part of hibernate? If I want to use hibernate with jpa, I have to use some of "javax.persistence.*" annotations?

Comment: In my opinion; if you need JPA annotations, you shouldn't avoid to not use JPA. On your case, JPA extends Hibernate and you need it, so why don't you just use the JPA with hibernate.

Comment: Why would you not want to use JPA where you can?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306793/why-jpa-and-hibernate-both-have-entity-and-table-annotations

Comment: These two questions are both mine, I don't think they are duplicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I want to use hibernate with jpa, I have to use some of
>   "javax.persistence.*" annotations?

Yes , you are right

The JPA spec. defines the JPA annotation  in the `javax.persistence` package. Hibernate not only implements JPA spec , but  extends it to adds more features . So , hibernate creates  their own annotations  which just extend the JPA annotation with the Hibernate features , and put these annotation inside the package `org.hibernate.annotations`

If there are no Hibernate specified features  added for that JPA annotation (eg `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`) , Hibernate will not make that annotation in their `org.hibernate.annotations` package and you have to use these annotation from  `javax.persistence` according to the JPA specification.

Normally ,people will use JPA annotations until they come across a situation  that requires to use hibernate features.