# Why jpa and hibernate both have "Entity" and "Table" annotations?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations

I use hibernate 3.6, and found there are such annotations:

```
javax.persistence.Entity
org.hibernate.annotations.Entity

javax.persistence.Table
org.hibernate.annotations.Table
```

Why hibernate provides its own? Is it a replacement of jpa one, or just a complement? Should(Can) I use them both together, like:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity
public class User {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

org.hibernate.annotations.Entity extends javax.persistence.Entity with hibernate features.

see: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Entity.html

Comment: So u have to use both annotations to be JPA-Compatible. If u use hibernate without JPA, the hibernate Entity only might work.

Comment: if you want to be JPA-Compatible then you use JPA annotations only; you do *not* use both.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You are not full JPA compatible, but the better way, if you really need these special hibernate features. The other way would be to drop the whole JPA-Stuff and use SessionFactory.